# Is there a Array Library in Python or Julia that enables Labelled Array Slicing and Sub-Slicing

Tags: python, arrays, julia, slice

In some data-structures (matrices) you might want the ability to slice the matrix by multiple labels, or at least have labeled slices, rather than slicing by index.

For example, imagine we have a matrix describing payments between companies. The columns are the expenditures (the payers) the rows are the (incomes) receivers. The matrix is square since every company is listed along both axes. The diagonal is zeros because a company doesn't pay money to itself (theoretically).

However now you want to slice this matrix by sector (manufacturing, agriculture) to find the agriculture payments sub-matrix. Or maybe you want to slice smaller and find how much manufacturing pays to grain companies. Is there a package that enables labelled slicing in a neat and readable way in either language?

Theoretical slicing syntax

```py
# Slicing array for agriculture
payments[payments.expenditures.agriculture, payments.incomes.agriculture]

# Slicing for manufacturing payments to agriculture->grain specifically
payments[payments.expenditures.manufacturing, payments.incomes.agriculture.grain]
```

In this case the `payments.expenditures.manufacturing` would just be something like 14:18 (total of 3 companies in manufacturing) and `payments.incomes.agriculture.grain` would be something like 7:8 (total of 1 company). But the syntax above is more readable than `payments[14:18, 7:8]`

You could theoretically have n-sized hierarchy in your slice. going from industry and categorizing down to specific product.

Wondering if there are any ways to do this within Python or Julia?

Or will I have to write something like this myself, I think it could be accomplished using a Tree-like data-structure that houses the range of index in each node.

Comment: There is something in Julia near what you want, called [NamedArrays.jl](https://github.com/davidavdav/NamedArrays.jl), where you can say `payments[agriculture, 7:8]` for example.

Comment: @AboAmmar I saw some packages, but I think this one allows only labeled indexes not labeled slices. I could like labeled indexes but something like python's xarray is a more mature project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JuMP.Containers has exactly the functionality you are asking for.
You can define arrays with custom indexes and then do the slicing over them.

```
julia> using JuMP.Containers

julia> a = DenseAxisArray(rand(3,3),[:a,:b,:c],[:d,:e,:f])
2-dimensional DenseAxisArray{Float64,2,...} with index sets:
    Dimension 1, [:a, :b, :c]
    Dimension 2, [:d, :e, :f]
And data, a 3×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.894139  0.797912  0.594439
 0.849874  0.916928  0.716711
 0.804051  0.320512  0.739498

julia> a[:b, :]
1-dimensional DenseAxisArray{Float64,1,...} with index sets:
    Dimension 1, [:d, :e, :f]
And data, a 3-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.849874338245389
 0.9169276864574099
 0.7167114738439391
```